# Passing an address of a pointer instead of a pointer as a function argument

Tags: c, freertos

So I'm trying to understand the argument passing to this function.

The second argument takes a pointer

```c
BaseType_t xQueueGenericSend( QueueHandle_t xQueue, const void * const pvItemToQueue, TickType_t xTicksToWait, const BaseType_t xCopyPosition ) PRIVILEGED_FUNCTION;
```

then how come passing an address of a pointer is legit?

```c
struct AMessage *pxMessage;
pxMessage = & xMessage;
xQueueGenericSend( xQueue2, ( void * ) &pxMessage, ( portTickType ) 0, queueSEND_TO_BACK );
```

Reference:
[http://web.ist.utl.pt/~ist11993/FRTOS-API/group___queue_management.html#xQueueGenericSend](http://web.ist.utl.pt/%7Eist11993/FRTOS-API/group___queue_management.html#xQueueGenericSend)

Comment: wouldn't you want to pass a pointer instead of an *address* of it? example: https://cplayground.com/?p=pony-hamster-louse

Comment: It is passing a pointer.

Comment: it's passing an address, no?

Comment: There's no implicit conversion in this case, it's explicit `(void *)`

Comment: @Pokloha An address is a pointer.

Comment: A pointer to X = the address of X. It is passing a pointer to a pointer = the address of a pointer = the address of a variable that stores the address of something else

Comment: are you saying `pxMessage` and `&pxMessage` are the same things?

Comment: The basic problem here is maybe the function is designed to take a certain kind of pointer, but it is declared to accept any kind of object pointer. So the compiler does not care, and it is not going to warn you: As far as it is concerned, you are passing a pointer, and the routine accepts any kind of object pointer, so there is no problem. If the function is designed to work with a certain kind of pointer, you will have to find out what that is and make sure you are passing that kind of pointer. And maybe change the declaration of the routine so that it is more specific about what it wants.

Comment: `pxMessage` is a pointer. `&pxMessage` is a different pointer. They may both be converted to `void *` and passed to the routine, as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: @CherryDT yes, you'd pass an address of a pointer in case you want a pointer to a pointer (2d array)...but how come it's equivalent to passing `*` as argument type?

Comment: I think the function declaration should have double-pointer i.e. `const void ** const pvItemToQueue`. Then it was okay to pass the address of a pointer.

Comment: @Pokloha they are not the same but both are a pointer. `pxMessage` is an `AMessage*` (**a pointer** to an `AMessage`) and `&pxMessage` is an `AMessage**` (**a pointer** to a pointer to an `AMessage`). Both are "**a pointer** to something" though (even if the something is another pointer) and hence both are convertible to `void*`.

Comment: If you imagine the `void` as a wildcard you'd see that `void*` => `(void)*` => `(AMessage*)*` => `AMessage**` does make sense.

Comment: okay so looks like `void*` really isn't limited to the (generic) types but also the variables. So `void*` could literally mean a pointer to a pointer, a pointer, triple pointer etc and of any type...if you don't use `void*` as the type, you'd need to use `<type>**` instead, yeah?

Comment: @SourabhChoure that's exactly what I thought but looks like with `void`, you don't need to worry about the specifics...

Answer (score 0):

If a subroutine wants to output a pointer, like where in the parse of your string it stopped, you pass it a pointer to that pointer, so it can write your pointer with that output.

Casting makes type checking quiet but you can ask for silly things.  A void pointer, by definition, can be cast or assigned to point to anything, including a pointer, a pointer to a pointer, a pointer to a pointer to a pointer, etc.  A pointer is just an unsigned long with a big attitude, the type it points to, and a cast changes that.

Comment: doesn't void pointer have more to do with the type than the pointer itself i.e pointer to pointer vs just a pointer? I removed `void*` as its type and it still compiles...

Comment: The type only becomes relevant when dereferenced to that level.  Above that level, the type is pointer.  An asterisk is equivalent, in some ways, to a {}, so type_x x[][][] is ***type_x, *x is still a pointer, **x is still a pointer, ***x is a type_x, x[0][0][0].

Comment: To create dynamic multidimensional arrays, x[] is an array of pointers to arrays of pointers, and x[][] is an arrays of pointers to arrays of type_x.  To avoid this, I often do multidimensional arrays in one dimension and expand the trailing dimensions to mod 2 values, so a dynamic array 7x8x9 becomes 7x16x16 and the one dimensional index on a,b,c is (((a<<4)+b)<<4)+c (no multiplying, space for speed, barrel shifters do shifts in one clock).

Answer (score 0):

freeRTOS queue function passes the message. If the message is the pointer you need to pas reference to it. Then this reference is being dereferenced.

In this case the pointer to message is going to be queued - not the message itself.

It works exactly as memcpy. memcpy parameters are `void *` and any pointer can be passed to this function.

Comment: what if you had just passed in `pxMessage`? wouldn't that be a pointer to a message too? also, how do you know if you wanna pass an address or the pointer itself given the type is `void`?

Comment: It does not have to know the type. When you create the queue you just say how long in the message. In this case `sizeof(pxMessage)`. I will stop this discussion - to understand this topic you must learn the pointers and freeRTOS as well. You take one function, not knowing how the queues work in this system. Before you learn this discussion is rather pointless

Comment: Not sure if you understood my point but thanks for the help